# Pragmatically access MenuItem Actionbar Android

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, menuitem

I have a menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_filter_selection"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_filter"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/sort">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/group_sort_selection"
            android:checkableBehavior="single"
            android:menuCategory="container" >
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_incoming"
                android:title="@string/incoming"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_outgoing"
                android:title="@string/outgoing"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_combined"
                android:checked="true"
                android:title="@string/combined"/>
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>

</menu>
```

and I want to access `menu_incoming` in code via index, not by id, using `Menu.getItem(int index)` method.

I have tried following code in `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`:

```
((Menu) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_filter_selection)).
    getItem(0).setChecked(true);
```

But obviously it is giving exception as `menu_filter_selection` is not a `Menu`. Any idea how to access `menu_incoming` via `Menu.getItem(int index)` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is, using [MenuItem.getSubMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getSubMenu%28%29):

```
menu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I found it and was posting it. I did it like this `menu.findItem(R.id.menu_filter_selection).getSubMenu().getItem(
    0).setChecked(true);`.